# Adding a path to @INC but not within the Perl script

Tags: perl

I'm an owner of a tool written in Perl and Java. One of the scripts uses modules like `JSON` and `Data::Dumper`.
My environment and my `@INC` know where those modules are located. But a user which uses my tool has an error:

```
Can't locate JSON.pm in @INC (@INC contains: <PATHS> .) at /tools/bin/myscript.pl line 15.
```

I understand how `@INC` works and I just wonder what would be the right way to solve this issue. We work at the same company (different regions) so the user does have permissions to the area which contain those modules.
From my side, the scripts works fine because my `@INC` does contain a path to an area with those modules in it.

From previous threads I have learned that I can set `PERL5LIB` with the area which contains (not recursive) the package. But that problem feels not good enough because then I'll have to specify multi paths (because JSON and Data::Dumper are not in the same area and `PERL5LIB` checks the modules in the directory but not recursive).

Also, from previous threads I have learned that I can run `perl -I myscript.pl` but it does not help because my the tool is mostly Java which executes Perl. Furthermore, I prefer not to change anything at the script itself, rather at the user's environment.

What would be the way to solve that kind of issue? Is there a way to "push" a path to `@INC` from Linux? How to prevent problems like that in the future?

Comment: https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq8.html#How-do-I-add-a-directory-to-my-include-path-(%40INC)-at-runtime%3f

Comment: Why not just normally install the CPAN modules your code depends on?

Comment: @robert They are installed but in a different area.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I can gather of your description, the `PERL5LIB` seems to be a good solution.

I don't know what you mean by "*`PERL5LIB` checks the modules in the directory but not recursive*", but `PERL5LIB` is a shell variable, normally set in your shell configuration files (while this can also be done  dynamically), to a *list* of directories. From [Environment (perlrun)](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#ENVIRONMENT), the `PERL5LIB` is

> A list of directories in which to look for Perl library files before looking in the standard library and the current directory. [...]

So you can set it to a suitable list of directories that covers all that is needed.

Make sure that it is an *environment* variable, by using [`export` in [ba]sh](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_02.html#sect_03_02_03)

```
export PERL5LIB="/path/to/dir1:/other/path/dir2:$HOME/inhome/dir3"
```

where the quotes are there in case there are spaces in directory names.  This line is normally entered in the file `~/.bashrc`

Or, use `setenv` if in `[t]csh`, with a following line to add to `~/.tcshrc`

```
setenv PERL5LIB "/path/to/dir1:/other/path/dir2:$HOME/inhome/dir3"
```

Comment: I meant that if I have the following structure: `/tools/main/dir1/JSON.pm` and `/tools/main/dir2/Data.pm` I cant use `setenv PERL5LIB /tools/main` because it fails to find those modules. I have to set the exact path (like `/tools/main/dir1/` for the first module). I think that its a problem of Perl versions. I use `5.14.1` and the user uses `5.7.1`. What configuration to change in order to set the right version from Linux perspective?

Comment: `5.7.1`? Are you sure. That version is 18 years old from April 2001 ...

Comment: 5.7.1 isn't even production release; it's a development version meant to allow developers to spot problems with the then-upcoming 5.8 production release before it actually came out.

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant `5.8.7`. Not sure why I said `5.7.1`.

Comment: @vesii No you are correct. Paths in `@INC` must be the root directory where modules are installed, they are not recursive - this is important for modules with multiple name components that are stored in subdirectories. So in your case, you must add both `/tools/main/dir1` and `/tools/main/dir2`.

Comment: @vesii  Is there a problem with adding both? Note, this (`PERL5LIB`) is a shell variable which your user sets for their account, in their configuration files. You set it as needed for yourself in your files.  So there should be no conflict.

Comment: The problem with `PERL5LIB` is because the user will have to set every time he will want to run the script. I think that the user should update his Perl version to `5.14.1` so he could use all of the modules I use, but how to do it?

Comment: @vesii  (1)  Well, yes, it is best that the user updates their Perl. They are more than 15 years behind.  (2) If that isn't possible, they can set `PERL5LIB` _in their shell configuration file_  ---  then every Perl program they run will have those directories (that are listed in the `PERL5LIB` variable) added to its list of directories to search for modules.  They don't need to "_set [it] every time_".

Comment: Oh, I see. Where can I read more about the configuration file?

Comment: @vesii I meant the `.bashrc` (or `.tcshrc` in your're in tcsh shell) file.  That's where you set environment variables, along with many other needs and goodies.

Comment: @vesii So if open your `.bashrc` (or `.tcshrc` if you're in tcsh) and add `export TEST=value` (`setenv TEST value` in tcsh), then in the future that variable will always be there. Try: once you add that to your `.bashrc` (or `.tcshrc`) close that terminal, open another one, and type `echo $TEST`.  (Instead of closing and opening you can type `source .bashrc` and the configuration is read in). That's an environment variable.  That's what you do with `PERL5LIB` and it's always set up as you log in.  So when a Perl program starts it's there for it.